# How can i return Future<T> using returns method in Bytebuddy?

Tags: java, java.util.concurrent, byte-buddy

I am intercepting a method which returns Future where i know that ‘T’ is subclass of ‘E’.
How can i use returns() method of `net.bytebuddy.matcher.ElementMatchers` to achieve that.
I want something like `returns(Future<isSubtypeOf(E.class)>)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can implement an `ElementMatcher<MethodDescription>` yourself, which is the easiest. Byte Buddy offers methods on the `TypeDescription.Genric` API which allows you to read all type information. Otherwise, `ElementMatchers` has factory methods for `returnsGeneric` where you can match a parameterized type as well.